# C++ Primer Exercise

Tags: c++

i just started to learn C++ , and come across 2 exercises in C++ Primer . 1 of this exercises i can't understand .

**Exercise 2.22 C++ Primer**
Assuming `p` is a pointer to `int`,explain the following code:

```
if (p) //....  
if (*p) //....
```

As i understand in 1 statement we checking condition of pointer p whether its `true` or `false`
In 2 statement all actions is same except this time we use dereference operator
If i'm wrong, can you tell me where my mistake.

And Next Exercise ,This exercise i cant understand
**Exercise 2.23**
Given a pointer `p`,can you determine whether `p` points to a valid object ? If so, how? If not , why not?

The thing i know is that when your variable initialized and have the same type as pointer then you might know is that your pointer points to valid object.  And also trying to access to invalid pointer can bring to code problem and that the compiler ant find this problem.
Is there something else about this Exercise can be added ? Or my guessing is wrong ?
Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming

```
int *p = NULL;
```

Then:

```
if (p)
```

checks whether p is NULL or not and will return false.

```
if (*p)
```

checks whether `(*p) == 0`, i.e. the integer pointed by `p` is 0 or not.

if you have

```
int *p;
```

i.e., without initializing it, then `p` will point to random address in your memory, and

```
if (p)
```

will most of the time return true. and

```
if (*p)
```

will give undefined behavior.

Comment: an additional point of clarification: usually, pointers are initialised to `NULL` (==`0`) before they hold a reference to an object. Additionally, factory functions (that instantiate objects) often return NULL on an error, instead of a valid pointer.

Comment: @gongzhitaao Thanks . This Pointers is real hell

Comment: @AlexGreat you will like it :)